# Other words to say "carro" in Portuguese-speaking countries

Tags: uso-de-palavras

> Eu vou de carro ao parque para fazer exercício.

I know in European Portuguese they call it differently. I tried looking it up but failed. Do you have other names for this transportation?

Comment: automóvel o veículo. Eu vou de carro, not em carro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Veículo** or **automóvel** can be used instead of **carro**.

**Viatura** for police car.

In other contexts we can associate *veículo* and *viatura* to other means of transport also: truck, bus and motorcycle.

Slang:
**Possante** for turbo (fast) car.
**Lata-velha** (calhambeque) for old car.

Comment: In Portugal at least, "viatura" is not for police cars. When a policeman stops someone on a civilian vehicle, they will say: "boa noite; a carta [de condução] e os documentos da **viatura**, por favor."

Comment: In Brasil: when a policeman stops someone on a civilian vehicle, they will say: "boa noite, a habilitação e os documentos do veículo, por favor". Driver's license = Carteira Nacional de Habilitação(CNH).

Comment: "Tira essa carroça da frente!", no cotidiano quase ninguém diria lata-velha. Veículo pode ser carro, ônibus, motocicleta, caminhão, etc. Automóvel geralmente é usado para carros, mas o significado da palavra não a restringe a somente carros.